# Caliburn Micro - Share data between ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Starting from the Caliburn Micro "Simple MDI" example. I would like to achieve the following:

I would like to share the reference of a class between the ViewModels. The shareme.count should be passed as reference to all the ViewModels. This would allow me to change it from within each ViewModel.

How can I achieve this close to Caliburn Micro convention?

**ShellViewModel.cs**

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive {

SharedClass _shareme;

public SharedClass shareme {
    get { return _shareme; }
    set {
        _shareme = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => shareme);
    }
}

public ShellViewModel() {
    shareme.count = 1;
}

public void OpenTab() {
    ActivateItem(new TabViewModel {
        DisplayName = "Tab " + shareme.count++
    });
}
```

**TabViewModel.cs**

```
public class TabViewModel : Screen {}
```

**AppBootstrapper.cs**

```
    public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase {
    SimpleContainer container;

    public AppBootstrapper() {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void Configure() {

        container = new SimpleContainer();

        container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
        container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
        container.PerRequest<IShell, ShellViewModel>();
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key) {
        var instance = container.GetInstance(service, key);
        if (instance != null)
            return instance;

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not locate any instances.");
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service) {
        return container.GetAllInstances(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance) {
        container.BuildUp(instance);
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Message passing with EventAggregator would probably be best solution.  Or pass it as a parameter when you are showing a new screen

Answer (score 1):

The will also serve as answer to your duplicate question.

EventAggregator isn't just for "events" you can message pass data to any or all viewmodels that are listening for message or event signature in question.

```
public class ViewModelA : Screen, IHandle<ShareMeMessageA>
{
  private readonly IEventAggregator _events;
  private int _sharemecount;
  public class ViewModelA(IEventAggregator events){

       _events = events;
       _events.Subscribe(this);
  }

  //... other bits out for brevity 
  //-- EDIT -- 
  public void SomeEventClick(){
    _event.PublishOnUiThread(new ShareMeMessageB(){ ...  etc ... });
  }

  protected override void Deactivated(bool close){
    _events.Unsubscribe(this);
  }

  private void Handle(ShareMeMessageA msg)
  {
      if(msg != null)
        sharemecount = msg.Count;
  }
}
```

as this is just an example you don't have to pass the class object at all you can pass any type you want bool, int, float, etc..

Comment: This is also what I found. However, this seems good as long as you do not have bidirectional transfer and a relationship between three ViewModels. Because I can not pass references, only instances, right?

Comment: Instances correct, not references.  Edited for clarity

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Once passing an instance of a class containing properties which fire if changed, how to get this NotifyOfPropertyChange events in both, the publishing and the receiving ViewModel? Is there an easy way?

Comment: `IHandle<T>` on all classes that need to see the change.  You aren't limited to the amount of `IHandle<T>`  or messages but it might come to a point were you have Message Spaghetti.  They can be of different types not just what I outlined or you have read online for the system